# DNS load balancing with health checks

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

I have a problem here.

We have a setup of compute instances on two different cloud regions from a cloud provider I would not mention except to stat that it is painful to work with.

Those instances are using (obviously) private.

We can't use a load balancing solution based on a VIP because this cloud provider does not allow cross-region private IPs so a NLB is out of the picture.

What we need is a DNS server (well, two, actually, at least) with A record health check capabilities. Let me place an example:

1. Service:

- Server A - Region 1 - IP 10.1.1.100
- Server B - Region 2 - IP 172.26.1.100

2. DNS balancers (sharing the same records and configuration database):

- DNS A - Region 1 - IP 10.1.1.50
- DNS B - Region 2 - IP 172.26.1.50
- DNS record 1: whatever.local - 10.1.1.50
- DNS record 2: whatever.local - 172.26.1.50

3. Clients:

- Client A - Any Region  - Any IP

4. Scenario A:

- Client A Has both DNS A and DNS B configured as DNS servers.
- Client A asks for whatever.local to DNS Server A
- Server A is offline
- DNS Server A has backend healthchecks and detects it and replies with Server's B IP (172.26.1.50)
- TTL is set to 0 (zero) or something equally low to avoid caching.

5. Scenario B:

- Client A Has both DNS A and DNS B configured as DNS servers.
- Client A asks for whatever.local, DNS Server A is down so DNS Server B replies
- Server B is offline
- DNS Server B has backend healthchecks and detects it and replies with Server's A IP (10.1.1.100)
- TTL is set to 0 (zero) or something equally low to avoid caching.

In essence: A DNS server that checks the health of DNS records' IPs.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

> Client A Has both DNS A and DNS B configured as DNS servers.

erm, you're heading for a world of pain having a machine use multiple DNS servers configured with different split data. You'd really need to build your own resolved stack on the monitoring host to get predictable behaviour.

The way to monitor this service is without splitting DNS:

```
service.example.com.  CNAME region1_service.example.com.
service.example.com.  CNAME region2_service.example.com.
region1_service.example.com. A 10.1.1.50
region2_service.example.com. A 172.26.1.50
```

And monitor each of:

- service.example.com
- region1_service.example.com
- region2_service.example.com

Alternatively your monitoring agent *may* support setting explicit addresses - so you can seperately monitor each instance. But then you have the complication of flagging an outage on BOTH nodes which as much more serious than an outage on one of the nodes.

You should also check HOW you monitoring client implements rrDNS. Failover detection time sticking to the rules is ~5 minutes but browsers apply a threshold of around 10 seconds for the initial connect, and <1 second for subsequent requests.

Comment: Hi @symcbean, maybe I wasn't clear enough. Both DNS servers will share the same configuration, hence, will give the same answers and have the same CNAME or A records. The idea is for them to be "smart" and healthcheck each record IP availability because a NLB is out of the picture. It is not a monitoring solution. When a client asks to one of this "smart" DNS servers, either of them, will be capable of health-checking their own records once a request is received and reply with the actual available IP. Just like a NLB but with a DNS broker...

Comment: Although DNS allows for very short TTLs, a *LOT* of relays will ignore this - one hour is a good rule of thumb for the minimum *effective* TTL. IMHO not good enough for high availability.